# I have a site Template , I want to create another site template based on this template but using different Master Page

Tags: 2007, development, site-template, solution-package, site

I have a Site Template A .wsp file, I want to create another Site Template B based on Site Template A but I want it have a different Master Page. I know how to do it in a site definition but I dont know how to do it using Site Template. I am using Sharepoint 2007 btw.

Comment: How are you creating the site template?  From site settings?  What happens when you try it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I just needed to changed the master page, so I changed it by uploading master to gallery and then going to Site Actions, Site Settings, Master Pages and changed the default master page to one I just uploaded, and then save site as a template, didn't required site definition anymore.